# How to create extra column in dataframe based on length of dataframe as an index value

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to create extra column in dataframe based on length of dataframe as an index value for dataframe

i am trying to do something like this

```
x = len(df3.columns)
df3['x+1'] = 'N/A'
```

It does create dataframe but not with index value 4 but with index value x+1

```
                          1  x+1  
        0          Bag (BG)  N/A  
        1        100.0 Each  N/A  
        2       0.0 / 0.001  N/A  
        3              0.01  N/A  
        4  4.0 x 3.5 x 1.25  N/A  
        5    10888277689268  N/A
```

I expect in place of X+1 it should be the number next to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need integer column simply remove `''`:

```
x = len(df3.columns)
df3[x + 1] = 'N/A'
```

If need string column one possible solution is use `f-strings`:

```
df3[f'{x + 1}'] = 'N/A'
```